# Scandal at Annapolis in 1934

Tags: military

According to the Wikipedia article on [Peyton Magruder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peyton_M._Magruder) he "resigned during his senior year of 1934 partially due to a scandal which has now become a part of Naval Academy lore." What was this scandal?

Comment: Is this really a history question? Some scandal in some school 81 years ago? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.b26.com/marauderman/peyton_magruder.htm:

> The subjects of the Annapolis legend, which any plebe can recite
>   complete with gestures, is a bath in Madeira and explains how Magruder
>   came to resign from the Naval Academy. Boiled down, a generally
>   accepted version goes like this: when the old battleship Wyoming, with
>   Magruder, and other midshipmen aboard, arrived at Funchal, Madeira, on
>   a training cruise in 1933, across the bay was a German merchantman
>   with future wives for South African colonists on its passenger list.
>
> Wyoming scuttlebutt quickly translated this into a shipload of
>   beauteous maidens. That night, Magruder and a classmate (now a
>   well-known submarine commander in the Pacific) were preparing to turn
>   in when the classmate decided he wanted a date with one of those
>   beauteous maidens. Before Magruder could dissuade him, he had dived
>   overboard front the gun deck. Magruder, knowing his bunkmate was a
>   poor swimmer, went after him. He should, however, have sung out "man
>   overboard" instead. By not so doing, he had, in Navy parlance,
>   unnecessarily endangered a life (his own). So the commendation for
>   saving his classmate was accompanied by a whopping block of demerits
>   for violating Navy regulations. He now had so many demerits that even
>   the most trivial offense would result in his automatic expulsion of
>   the Academy. Several months later, he decided discretion was the
>   better part of valor and resigned. He is more useful to the nation
>   where lie is, however, than he could ever have been as a still quite
>   junior naval officer

Another version of the story here:

http://www.usna.com/NC/History/SeaStories/1934/FunchalMedieraCaper.htm