# What did US Supreme Court Justice Potter Stewart study as an undergraduate?

Tags: united-states, famous-people

[Potter Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potter_Stewart) graduated as an undergraduate in 1937 from Yale University, and then served a Fellowship of one year at Cambridge University; but in what subjects did he major or specialise?

I am curious because when asked about the best writer on the Court, Justice John Paul Stevens has repeatedly distinguished and selected Justice Stewart as the best writer.

Comment: Bit puzzled about the close votes here. This [recent question](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/26970/739) is similarly mundane, yet it didn't attract any close votes and was answered.

Comment: @Yannis A historical scandal is *considerably less mudane* than what classes someone took for their Bachelor of Arts degree.

Comment: @Yannis probably because the word "scandal" implies public knowledge and some degree of notioriety. That said, being a relevant, public figure, I do not see the question as "harmful" enough as to grant a negative/close votes (at best, leaving it unanswered).

Comment: @Yannis I am puzzled also; I thank you and user 'SJuan76' for the support.

Comment: Voting to close, trivia of no historical significance. First of all, Potter Stewart is not a particularly famous Justice, so very little he that he did has historical significance, and what he may have studied or not studied in school is patently trivial.

Comment: @TylerDurden `Potter Stewart is not a particularly famous Justice`: On what basis do you allege this? `what he may have studied or not studied in school is patently trivial` : How is this 'patently trivial'? Your undergraduate major does affect preparation for law; philosophy majors have been proven to score better on LSATs than other majors.

Comment: @LePressentiment Name an important decision that Stewart wrote (not a concurrence). According to the Wikipedia, it appears the most important opinion he wrote was Sierra Club v. Morton, an relatively minor case. He is simply not an important justice. I studied Constitutional Law in college under Robert George, and in that course Potter Stewart was never even mentioned once.

Comment: @TylerDurden 1. Does your comment presume a 'False Cause', in presuming that a justice's importance derives only from the number of decisions composed by him/her? 2. Please correct me if I erred, but I am inferring from your silence that we need not further discuss your other assertion: `what he may have studied or not studied in school is patently trivial`.

Comment: @LePressentiment I don't really see what the historical importance is of this judge or how his youthful studies are historically significant. In Schwartz's book "A History of the Supreme Court" Stewart is barely mentioned at all and no decision he wrote is mentioned. By any reasonable criteria he is not an important Justice.

Comment: Whether you or I think Justice Stewart is/was "of historical importance" is not really relevant, to this question. If, in fact, Justice Stevens, who _was_ suitably important, made statements to the effect that Justice Stewart was "the best writer (of the past Courts)", then understanding what background Justice Stewart had might enable us to understand _why Stevens asserted this_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a 2002 article by Joel Jacobsen, Potter Stewart's undergraduate degree was a Bachelor of Arts  in English.  A pdf file of this article can be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.uakron.edu/dotAsset/727261.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj32N7vqoXKAhUG5yYKHboWCikQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNEURIx2MZTKlbToLAiYoLlHTxCETg&sig2=AWIpzoTZ4RMoVM1UlNrn3w).